# How to split a DataFrame column value on linefeed and create a new column with the last 2 items (lines)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to split a column value with line feeds and create a new column with the two last items (lines)

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
  ["001\r\nLuc  Krier\r\n2363  Ryan Road, Long Lake South Dakota"],
  ["002\r\nJeanny  Thorn\r\n2263 Patton Lane Raleigh North Carolina"],
  ["003\r\nTeddy E Beecher\r\n2839 Hartland Avenue Fond Du Lac Wisconsin"],
  ["004\r\nPhilippe  Schauss\r\n1 Im Oberdorf Allemagne"],
 ["005\r\nMeindert I Tholen\r\nHagedoornweg 138 Amsterdam"]
]).toDF("s")
```

This is not working (None value):

```
df.withColumn('last_2', split(df.s, '\r\n')[-2])
```

Comment: any sample data?

Comment: Added simple sample. Original data contains more lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this simply by substring_index function as

```
df1.withColumn('last2',f.substring_index('s','\r\n',-2)).drop('s').show(10,False)

+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|last2                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|Luc  Krier
2363  Ryan Road, Long Lake South Dakota        |
|Jeanny  Thorn
2263 Patton Lane Raleigh North Carolina     |
|Teddy E Beecher
2839 Hartland Avenue Fond Du Lac Wisconsin|
|Philippe  Schauss
1 Im Oberdorf Allemagne                 |
|Meindert I Tholen
Hagedoornweg 138 Amsterdam              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i am also facing the same issue with negative indexing, but positive indexing works.
I tried with the slice function, and it worked fine. can you try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([ ["001\r\nLuc Krier\r\n2363 Ryan Road, Long Lake South Dakota"], ["002\r\n\Jeanny Thorn\rn2263 Patton Lane Raleigh North Carolina"], ["003\r\nTeddy E Beecher\r\n2839 Hartland Avenue Fond Du Lac Wisconsin"], ["004\r\n\Philippe Schauss\r\n1 Im Oberdorf Allemagne"], ["005\r\n\Meindert I Tholen\r\nHagedoornweg 138 Amsterdam"] ]).toDF("s")
df_r = df1.withColumn('spl',F.split(F.col('s'),'\r\n'))
df_res = df_r.withColumn("res",F.slice(F.col("spl"),-1,1))
```

Answer (score -1):

perhaps this is helpful -

```scala
val sDF = Seq("""001\r\nLuc  Krier\r\n2363  Ryan Road, Long Lake South Dakota""",
      """002\r\nJeanny  Thorn\r\n2263 Patton Lane Raleigh North Carolina""",
      """003\r\nTeddy E Beecher\r\n2839 Hartland Avenue Fond Du Lac Wisconsin""",
      """004\r\nPhilippe  Schauss\r\n1 Im Oberdorf Allemagne""",
      """005\r\nMeindert I Tholen\r\nHagedoornweg 138 Amsterdam""").toDF("""s""")

   val processedDF = sDF.withColumn("col1", slice(split(col("s"), """\\r\\n"""), -2, 2))
    processedDF.show(false)
    processedDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |s                                                                   |col1                                                         |
      * +--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |001\r\nLuc  Krier\r\n2363  Ryan Road, Long Lake South Dakota        |[Luc  Krier, 2363  Ryan Road, Long Lake South Dakota]        |
      * |002\r\nJeanny  Thorn\r\n2263 Patton Lane Raleigh North Carolina     |[Jeanny  Thorn, 2263 Patton Lane Raleigh North Carolina]     |
      * |003\r\nTeddy E Beecher\r\n2839 Hartland Avenue Fond Du Lac Wisconsin|[Teddy E Beecher, 2839 Hartland Avenue Fond Du Lac Wisconsin]|
      * |004\r\nPhilippe  Schauss\r\n1 Im Oberdorf Allemagne                 |[Philippe  Schauss, 1 Im Oberdorf Allemagne]                 |
      * |005\r\nMeindert I Tholen\r\nHagedoornweg 138 Amsterdam              |[Meindert I Tholen, Hagedoornweg 138 Amsterdam]              |
      * +--------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- s: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- col1: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
      */
```

Comment: downvoter...Please specify reasons before downvoting an answer